# Why is my Debugger in VSCode not working with Rust after Mac Update to Sonoma 14.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I am running into an error with using VSCode's debugger for my Rust projects. It worked before the OS update, but now I am running into an issue. My Mac is a 2019 Macbook Pro with a x86 chip.

To illustrate what is going wrong I created a simple Rust project with just hello world.

[image]

It compiles just file, but when I hit the `Debug` above `main` I get this in by Debug Console

```
Console is in 'commands' mode, prefix expressions with '?'.
Launching: /Users/my_account/Desktop/test/target/debug/test
Launched process 5903
Process exited with code -1.
```

Also, I've noticed when I first open VSCode, rust analyzer is this odd color and it states `Failed to spawn one or more proc-macro servers`, but when I hit reload workspace it's returns to the original blue color of my of editor.

**Error**

[image]

**OK**

[image]

When I look into the Output tab in VSCode, it states nothing for the Rust Analyzer, so I am assuming that this means everything is OK on the Rust Analyzer side of things?

What I have tried:

- Reinstalling Rust
- Updating Rust via `rustup`
- reinstalling rust analyzer
- Making this simple project seeing if it was a set up issue.
- Updated command line tools
- Updated LLDB

Any help is greatly appreciated! : )

Comment: This sounds vaguely like you might need to re-accept the Xcode license agreement if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: Thank you! I did reaccept this when I launched Xcode, and then I restarted my Mac, but the issue persists. Still the same `Failed to spawn one or more proc-macro servers` and no debugging.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Deleting `~/.vscode/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.10.0/lldb/bin/debugserver` worked for me.

The comments on github indicate that this forces the codelldb plugin to fallback to using the system debugserver.

references:

- https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/issues/999
- https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/discussions/456#discussioncomment-874122

Comment: this also resolved my issue on MacOS 14 too

Comment: This also solved my problem but `debugserver` file was in `...../lldb/bin/` folder.